# Pivot table analysis in R and plotting based on subset data

Tags: r, pivot-table

```
lake                     date            P          N           C
East Long Lake       9/5/1994          21.9      254.8
East Long Lake       9/5/1994          30.1     1190.0       257.0
East Long Lake       9/5/1994          20.5      256.6
East Long Lake       9/5/1994          22.1      249.0
East Long Lake       9/5/1994         212.5     2011.6      1090.6
Central Long Lake   6/30/1995          22.9       91.1
Central Long Lake   6/30/1995     
Peter Lake           7/6/1994         41.9        527.2        29.6
Peter Lake           7/6/1994         138.8      1994.0      1409.6
Sparkling lake      7/13/1994          19.1       746.7        22.6 
Sparkling Lake      7/13/1994         19.2        21.3
```

I wanted to analyze data in couple of ways (just like pivot table in excel)

1. For each date (day) I have multiple values. I need to calculate mean for P,N,C by date (single day only, because I still want daily data) separately for each lake.
2. One point of caution is that my missing values are not zeros. So average should not be affected by those missing values. 
   3) Then Plotting it by lake.  So multiple plots where date will be on x axis and (P,N,C) on Y axis with

I did that analysis in excel by pivot table and result looks like that. But using excel is tedious. So I am looking for doing it in R.

```
lake                     date            P          N           C
East Long Lake       9/5/1994          61.42       792.4        673.8
Central Long Lake   6/30/1995          22.9        91.1
Peter Lake           7/6/1994          90.35      1260.6        719.6
Sparkling Lake      7/13/1994          19.15       384           22.6
```

Comment: This is easier than I thought it would be. Use data.table to get what you're looking for and then plot similarly to the last question you asked. `setDT(dat); dat = dat[ .(P = mean(P, na.rm = T), N = mean(N, na.rm=T), C = mean(C, na.rm=T)), by = .(lake, date)]` Hope this helps!

Comment: Error in `dat[ .(P = mean(P, na.rm = T), N = mean(N, na.rm=T), C = mean(C, na.rm=T)), by = .(lake, date)]
  'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j                                                                                  @Kristofersen i tried it but getting an error

Comment: sorry, forgot the first comma. Try this: `setDT(dat); dat = dat[ , .(P = mean(P, na.rm = T), N = mean(N, na.rm=T), C = mean(C, na.rm=T)), by = .(lake, date)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and assuming `mydf` is your data, we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
    group_by(lake, date) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm = T)
```